# how to get percentage of predicted value in Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have already used [object_detection_tutorial.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) to display object detector with percentage of predicted value,but the variable `num_detections` is a `TensorVariable` such as `Tensor("num_detections:0", dtype=float32)` ,so how can I print the percentage of predicted value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with `num_detections` is a TensorVariable? As you can see from their code, they're returning this tensor, `num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')`. In this case `num_detections` is by default 100 because they trained their model this way. To get the percentage of predicted value, you rather need the `scores`. Let's say that your threshold is at 0.5, you could calculate the percentage of predicted value this way:

```
import numpy as np

threshold = 0.5 # in order to get higher percentages you need to lower this number; usually at 0.01 you get 100% predicted objects
print(len(np.where(scores[0] > threshold)[0]) / num_detections[0])
```

Comment: thanks,but how can I check my threshold?I tried the command,but it prints constant 0.01 rather than correct percentage of predicted value.I think myabe something is wrong with my threshold.

Comment: The threshold is at 0.5 in my example as you can see. I've realized that there is an error in my answer. The output of `np.where()` is an array so that the length is always one so that's why it's constantly 0.1. See my updated answer. It should work now!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answering!It works now!